# How to remove form validation in D8 under certain conditions?

Tags: forms, 8

I'm trying to save a node as a draft, but only if we are saving as a draft (Workbench Moderation). Otherwise, validation should be run as normal.

The user must be allowed to save a node in any state, including empty values in required fields.

Should I instead be setting all fields as not required and adding my own validation function?

Comment: You can make these fields as optional from the field configuration and then use hook_entity_presave, check the moderation state, and do your logic on it.